# Why is the image being stretched and compressed when the missing constraints are being added?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I add the missing constraints, but the image is being stretched and compressed. How do I fix it so the image will be have the same size?

[image: Image of how the imageview looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use content mode

```
contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
```

adding a constraint by xcode it would be change according to view so give your constraint for top and bottom

**for swift**
Somewhat confusingly, Swift drops the prefix for ObjC enum values:

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: Where would I add this?

Comment: In storyboard for ui image 
or programatically myimg.contenMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Comment: It is 'UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit' for swift 2.0, but other than that it works.

Comment: i did the same thing for this page, but I still get messed up images. http://puu.sh/lBpqx/1090020972.png